How to run useGSAP hook only after certain elements are rendered in react
so i have this members page where i fetch data from a json and then according to the size of team the width of #membersBox will be set once they are loaded . so the issue over here is i am using gsap to animate it and gsap runs before the width is set thus the variable "H" is set to 0, and my animation dosen't work . how do i solve it? Here is the code:
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import gsap from "gsap";
import { useGSAP } from "@gsap/react";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";
import './membersPage.css'
import data from './members.json'

const membersPage = () => {
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
useGSAP(() => {
    const H = document.querySelector("#membersBox").clientWidth;
    let mm = gsap.matchMedia();
    mm.add("(max-width: 767px)", () => {
        gsap.to(".teamBox", {
            x: -H - 1300,
            scrollTrigger: {
                trigger: ".teamWrap",
                scroller: "body",
                start: "top 0%",
                end: `top -${H / 5}%`,
                scrub: 2,
                pin: true,
            },
        });
    });
    mm.add("(min-width: 768px)", () => {
        gsap.to(".teamBox", {
            x: -H - 300,
            scrollTrigger: {
                trigger: ".teamWrap",
                scroller: "body",
                start: "top 0%",
                end: `top -${H / 2}%`,
                scrub: 2,
                pin: true,
            },
        });
    });
})

const [team, setTeam] = useState('')
// let [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
useEffect(() => {
    // setTeam(searchParams.get("team"))
    var len = data['web'].length
    if (len % 2 != 0) {
        len = len + 1
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (!document.getElementById(`wave${i}`)) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    document.getElementById('wave').innerHTML += `
                    <div className="waveBox">
                    <img id="wave${i}" style="position: relative;" src="/PublicAssets/teamWave.svg" alt="" key=${i} />
                    </div>
                    `
                }
                else {
                    let leftVal = i * 28
                    document.getElementById('wave').innerHTML += `
                    <div className="waveBox">
                    <img id="wave${i}" style="position: relative;left: -${leftVal}px;" src="/PublicAssets/teamWave.svg" alt="" key=${i} />
                    </div>
                    `
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (!document.getElementById(`wave${i}`)) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    document.getElementById('wave').innerHTML += `
                    <div className="waveBox">
                    <img id="wave${i}" style="position: relative;" src="/PublicAssets/teamWave.svg" alt="" key=${i} />
                    </div>
                    `
                }
                else {
                    let leftVal = i * 28
                    document.getElementById('wave').innerHTML += `
                    <div className="waveBox">
                    <img id="wave${i}" style="position: relative;left: -${leftVal}px;" src="/PublicAssets/teamWave.svg" alt="" key=${i} />
                    </div>
                    `
                }
            }
        }
    }
    data['web'].forEach((e, i) => {
        if (!document.getElementById(`member${i}`)) {
            if (i == 0) {
                document.getElementById('membersBox').innerHTML += `
                <div className="member" id="member${i}" style="left:70px;flex-direction: column-reverse;bottom:0px">
                <div id="teamDetailCont">
                    <div id="memName">${e.name}</div>
                    <div id="msg">"${e.msg}"</div>
                </div>
                <div id="mask">
                <img id="teamImg" src="${e.img}" alt="" />
                </div>
                </div>
                `
            }
            else {
                var bottom = i % 2 == 0 ? 0 : -250
                var colDirection = i % 2 != 0 ? 'column' : 'column-reverse'
                var Left = Number(document.getElementById(`member${i - 1}`).style.left.replace('px', '')) + 135
                document.getElementById('membersBox').innerHTML += `
                <div className="member" id="member${i}" style="left:${Left}px;flex-direction: ${colDirection};bottom:${bottom}px">
                <div id="teamDetailCont">
                    <div id="memName">${e.name}</div>
                    <div id="msg">"${e.msg}"</div>
                </div>
                <div id="mask"> 
                <img id="teamImg" src="${e.img}" alt="" />
                </div>
                </div>
                `
            }
        }
    });

}, [])
return (
    <>
        <div className='teamWrap'>
            <div className="teamCont">
                <div className="teamHead">
                    <h1>Meet the minds behind the <span style={{ position: 'absolute', paddingLeft: '17px' }} >magic</span></h1>
                    <h1 className='teamNameHead' >The <span className='headHighlight'>{team}</span>{team.toLowerCase() == "board" ? " Members" : " Team"}</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="teamBox">
                    <div id='wave' className="wave"></div>
                    <div id="membersBox"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
)

}
export default membersPage

Why are you creating children of wave and memberBox with innerHTML instead of jsx ?

@remix23 how do i do it ?

I am writing an answer :)

@remix23 yes please thank you

Was my answer helpful to you?

I have removed imports because I am getting them from a CDN, obviously you can keep your imports ^^
I have factorized your rendering conditions (less ifs) but it should render the same.
Avoid at all cost doing innerHTML manipulation while using React !
It seems you did not know how to use loops in react, note the usual:
  <div>
    {
      array.map((element, index) => {
        // compute something if you need to and return the constructed element
        return (
           <span>{element.name /* or whatever with element */}</span>
        );
      })
     }
  </div>

If you do not have an array to begin with (for loop with length),you can construct one on the fly this way:
  [...Array(12)].map((_, index) => {
    // Note that '_' is just a regular variable name,
    // but the value is undefined in this case so
    // I name it '_' to help visually ignore it

  })

Since you GSAP code requires your elements to have a size, wait for your component to be mounted. Note what I did with useEffect, setMounted.


// import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
// import gsap from "gsap";
// import { useGSAP } from "@gsap/react";
// import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";
// import './membersPage.css'
// import data from './members.json'

const { useEffect, useState, Fragment } =  React;
const data = {
  web: [
    {
      name: 'name1',
      msg:'msg1',
      img: 'img1'
    },
    {
      name: 'name2',
      msg:'msg2',
      img: 'img2'
    },
    {
      name: 'name3',
      msg:'msg3',
      img: 'img3'
    }
  ]
};

// fake useGSAP, remove in your code, useGSAP also allows dependencies
const useGSAP = useEffect;

const MembersPage = () => {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);
  useGSAP(() => {
    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }
    // gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
    const H = document.querySelector("#membersBox").clientWidth;
    // removed gsap code we are only testing the width (H)
    console.log(H);
  }, [mounted]);

  const [team, setTeam] = useState('');
  // let [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  useEffect(() => {
    // setTeam(searchParams.get("team"))
    setMounted(true)
    

  }, []);
  var len = data['web'].length;
  // if len is odd, make len even by adding 1
  if (len % 2 !== 0) {
      len++;
  }
  return (
      <div className='teamWrap'>
          <div className="teamCont">
              <div className="teamHead">
                  <h1>
                    Meet the minds behind the
                    <span style={{ position: 'absolute', paddingLeft: '17px' }}>
                      magic
                    </span>
                  </h1>
                  <h1 className='teamNameHead' >
                    The
                    <span className='headHighlight'>{team}</span>
                    {team.toLowerCase() == "board" ? " Members" : " Team"}
                  </h1>
              </div>
              <div className="teamBox">
                  <div id='wave' className="wave">
                    {
                      [...Array(len)].map((_, i) => { 
                        // if i === 0 then leftVal === 0
                        let leftVal = i * 28;
                        return (
                          <div class="waveBox">
                            <img
                              id={`wave${i}`}
                              style={{ position: 'relative', left: -leftVal }}
                              src="/PublicAssets/teamWave.svg"
                              alt="teamWave"
                              key={i}
                            />
                          </div>
                        );
                        
                      })
                    }
                  </div>
                  <div id="membersBox">
                    {
                      data['web'].map((e, i) => {
                        var bottom = i % 2 === 0 ? 0 : -250;
                        var colDirection = i % 2 !== 0 ? 'column' : 'column-reverse';
                        var Left = 70 + 135 * i;
                        return(
                          <div
                            className="member"
                            id={`member${i}`}
                            style={{ left: Left, flexDirection: colDirection, bottom: bottom }}
                          >
                            <div id="teamDetailCont">
                                <div id="memName">{e.name}</div>
                                <div id="msg">"{e.msg}"</div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="mask">
                              <img id="teamImg" src={e.img} alt={`img${i+1}`} />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        );
                      })
                    }
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<MembersPage />, document.getElementById('root'));
/* DO NOT USE THIS CSS, KEEP YOURS*/
#wave {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid violet;
}
#membersBox {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.waveBox {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  /* min-width, min-height to simulate missing image, remove on your side */
  min-width: 100px; 
  min-height: 50px;
}
.member {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  min-width: 100px; 
  min-height: 50px;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>



